# HTML - set Bootstrap Left Menu as not fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the left sidebar of the popular bootstrap themes behave like the main content?

Please see [**this example.**](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/)

As you can see, the "main content" is scrolling, but the left sidebar is fixed as well as the header. How can I do, so the left sidebar is scrolling along with the main content (but still full height)?

Comment: Bootstrap has got [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) for this.

Comment: As mentioned this can be achieved using the Affix plugin. For anyone who might be interested how this plugin works, have a look at this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstraps-affix-scrollspy-plugins/

Comment: Try something like this: http://bootply.com/render/128936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly cut out your left nav from top nav. Because, you need to fixed top navigation. if you put your left nav in top nav it will also fixed, which you are not want.
2. Then change the css for `.side-nav` `fixed` to `absolute`. below the example.

css--

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .side-nav {
    position: absolute;/* Changed*/
    top: 51px;
    left: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    margin-left: -225px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #222;
    }
```